# Any recommendations for a good disk imaging software package for Windows XP, free if possible?

Tags: windows-xp, clone, disk-utility

I've always used Ghost at work, but at home I don't have a copy.

Can anyone recommend some software which will image my main windows XP system partition to another partition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tried any of these out but maybe you can find a useful option in [this link.](http://www.thefreecountry.com/utilities/backupandimage.shtml#imaging)

[Macrium Reflect](http://www.macrium.com/ReflectFree.asp) looks good and it has a free edition that does imaging. [Clonezilla](http://www.clonezilla.org/) seems to be an open source option. Take your pick.

Answer (score 1):

My favourite is [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php?id=start) on a bootable USB stick as it has Clonezilla + half a ton of other useful apps for computer setup and testing.

You can make up a bootable Parted Magic USB stick easily with [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)